Can you keep playing in the doomed world of Expedition 13 - Adrift?
Recently No Man's Sky introduced an alternate way to start an Expedition from a terminal on the Anomaly instead of using an alternate save slot.
I want to use the terminal for Expedition 13 but I was wondering if the Expedition "anomalies" have any lingering effect on a CONVERTED post expedition save, something that obviously you can't do if you start your run at the Terminal.
Therefore I just wanted to confirm a thing.
Can you by any mean finish the Expedition on a separate slot but never revert to the regular universe? Can you somehow "sever the thread of prophecy and persist in the doomed world you have created?"

In prior expeditions, this has not been possible, and there is no in-game text suggesting that Adrift will work differently. Some fans have speculated that Adrift might become a new game mode, but to my knowledge, Hello Games has not said anything to that effect. It is most prudent to assume that separate Adrift saves will convert to Normal mode after the expedition ends.

While this is also my basic reasoning, forgive me for not accepting your answer. What I am seeking is an actual confirmation from someone who tried the procedure to save me the time. While it is true that no expedition was ever made "permanent", the specific characteristics of Adrift could have been implemented by assigning it to a "special" galaxy (maybe one of the "shadow galaxies??), in which case I wouldn't exclude the possibility of said "special" galaxy to stay "special" even after the event (after all, some expeditions did cause some weird changes, see the Assembled Construct)

@Ꮢedacted: What exactly do you want people to try doing? You can finish the expedition, or you can wait for time to expire (or advance the system clock and expire it by hand, but nobody knows what updates will drop between now and end day, so the real game on the real clock might ultimately do something different). If there was a "do something else" button, I imagine we would have heard about it by now. (Also, it is most likely not in a special galaxy, because bases carry over to the main save slot, if the expedition is started from the Anomaly, and they would not match any terrain in Euclid.)
